# Show that N is a norm on V

Tags: linear-algebra

Definitions:

Let $V$ be a vector space with the real numbers as scalars.

---

A function $A:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called a **bilinear form** if  $A(\alpha a+\beta b, c) = \alpha A(a,c)+\beta A(b,c)$ and $A(a, \beta b + \gamma c) = \beta A(a,b)+\gamma A(a,c)$ for all scalars $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and vectors $a,b,c \in V$.

---

A bilinear form is called **positive definite** if $A(x,x)>0$, unless $x=\vec{0}$.

---

A **norm** on $V$ is a function $N:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

(i) $N(v) \ge 0$ for all $v \in V$

(ii) $N(v) = 0$ if and only if $v = \vec{0}$

(iii) $N(u+v) \le N(u)+N(v)$ for all $u,v \in V$

(iv) $N(\alpha v) = |\alpha|N(v)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v \in V$

---

---

I need to show that if $A$ is a positive definite bilinear form on $V$, then $N(v)=\sqrt{A(v,v)}$ defines a norm on $V$. I have shown that (i), (ii), and (iv) hold, but not (iii). Since (i) holds, it is sufficient to show that $(N(u) + N(v))^2 \ge (N(u+v))^2$. So

$(N(u+v))^2= (N(u))^2 + A(u,v) + A(v,u) + (N(v))^2$

$(N(u) + N(v))^2 = (N(u))^2 + 2N(u)N(v) + (N(v))^2$

$\Rightarrow (N(u) + N(v))^2 - (N(u+v))^2 = 2N(u)N(v)-A(u,v)-A(v,u)$

I need to show that $2N(u)N(v) \ge A(u,v)+A(v,u)$, but I have not found a way to do that. It is also important to state that this problem comes from Bert Mendelson's *Introduction to Topology Third Edition* and not from a linear algebra textbook. I have not rigorously studied linear algebra, so I am unaware of any commonly known results that might help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$0 \leq A(u+tv,u+tv) = A(u,u) + t(A(u,v)+A(v,u)) + t^2A(v,v)$$

This is a quadratic in $t$ and it is non-negative. Therefore, its discriminant must be non-positive. That is:
$$(A(u,v)+A(v,u))^2 - 4N(v)^2N(u)^2 \leq 0$$

$$[(A(u,v)+A(v,u))-2N(v)N(u)] \cdot [(A(u,v)+A(v,u))+ 2N(v)N(u)] \leq 0$$
Now, there are two possibilities. One of them must be negative and one of them must be positive. What you want is the situation where:
$$A(u,v)+A(v,u)-2N(v)N(u) \leq 0$$
Let's consider the situation where:
$$A(u,v)+A(v,u) -2N(v)N(u) \geq 0$$
Then, we must have that:
$$A(u,v)+A(v,u) + 2N(v)N(u) \leq 0$$
So, it follows that $-4N(v)N(u) \geq 0$. This implies that $N(v)N(u) = 0$ so at least one of these two quantities must be $0$. But if we choose non-zero $u$ and $v$, then this is not possible. Hence, it follows that:
$$A(u,v)+A(v,u) -2N(v)N(u) \leq 0$$
as was desired.

Comment: Thank you! I had not thought of using this strategy.

Comment: No problem at all, this is actually the method you use to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality. You'll learn about that in a general setting when you do study linear algebra more rigorously